# fabric.js set the objects to new position but the event target not followed

Tags: fabricjs

```
var that = this;
var mouseEvents = this.mouseEvents();
this.timeAxis.on('mouseover', mouseEvents.timeAxisOver);
this.timeAxis.on('mouseout', mouseEvents.timeAxisOut);
this.canvas.on('mouse:over', mouseEvents.canvasOver);
this.canvas.on('mouse:out', mouseEvents.canvasOut);
this.canvas.on('mouse:down', mouseEvents.canvasDown);
this.startPoint.on('mousedown', function(e) {
  var originPos = new Array();
  that.canvas.getObjects().map(function(obj, i) {
    originPos.push({
      x: obj.left,
      y: obj.top
    });
  });
  this.originPos = originPos;
  this.pos = that.canvas.getPointer(e.e);
});
this.startPoint.on('moving', function(e) {
  var currPos = that.canvas.getPointer(e.e),
    originPos = this.originPos,
    moveX = currPos.x - this.pos.x,
    moveY = currPos.y - this.pos.y;
  that.canvas.forEachObject(function(obj, i) {
    obj.set({
      left: originPos[i].x + moveX,
      top: originPos[i].y + moveY
    })
  });
  that.canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paulo/4L5u6hr8/3/)

I am a new to fabric.js and now I have a problem.I am trying to find some solution but it isn't working.
When I move the object by set method, the object moved but it's event doesn't follow, see in the code. The event target just stay in the previous position even if I rebind the event.so the problem is How can I make the event follow the object when I set the new position.

Comment: can you make a snippet?

Comment: ok,this is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paulo/4L5u6hr8/3/) demo

Comment: You want only that another circle to move or all the objects?

Comment: this is not the point.In jsFiddle,i add a 'mouseover' event on  circle1 and then set the new position of it,but it's event target stay in the original position.this is not what i want.i need it's event follow the object.maybe you have better way to do this.wish you understand,forgive my poor english.thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
object.setCoords();
```

Comment: This fixed it for me.